# How to save scroll posotion before re-render and set scroll position to the saved position - React JS

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-hooks

I have a  functional component in React JS. I need to save the scroll position before each re-render and set the scroll to the previous position.

```
export function Calender(props) {
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState([0, 0]);
    const handleClick = ()=> {
        setScrollPosition([window.screenX,window.ScreenY])
        //api call happens and props get changed which causes a rerender
    }

    useEffect( ()=>{
        window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0],scrollPosition[1])
    })

    return (
       <div >
           <button onClick={()=>{handleClick}} >Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

is not working for me. How can i do this?

Comment: Scroll to... where or what? Getting the current scroll height is pretty simple, and any websearch for "javascript get scroll position" will tell you how to do that. Setting the current scroll position is equally simple, so it kind of feels like you didn't actually search for how to do this yet?

Comment: i have to save the current screen position where i am. and after an api call component gets re-rendered. Then screen location is set as top. But i have to set this to the previous position.

Comment: Yes, and? Save the scroll position, then trigger the rerender, then as part of the post-render behaviour you set the scroll position to that saved scroll position, and then you clear the saved value.

Comment: scroll position is not set in the screen. That is the issue. I am actually using this code useEffect(()=>{window.scrollTo(prevX, prevY)})

Comment: No you don't. Your post says you're using `window.scrollTo()` without any arguments, and not in any function in particular. If you're using something else, please update your post to show what you're _actually_ doing, ideally as an [mcve] so people can see everything they need to see to understand what's going on start to finish.

Comment: i have updated the question with example. please have a look

Comment: Thank you. It looks you're storing screenX/screenY, rather than scrollX/scrollY.

Comment: I have trired with scrollX/scrollY .which still not working

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description: what errors do you get? And if you don't get any errors, put `console.log(scrollPosition)` in your hook and your effect: what _values_ do you see?